# How to exit from while loop during Pyserial Xbee communication?

Tags: python, pyserial

As a part of  my project I am sending bytes over one xbee to another . I have Python code that works fine , except one thing.

In the following receiver code , I have to add some more statements after everything has been received successfully. The problem is , as there is while true condition ( used for continuously receiving packets ) , whatever statements I added after the code will run infinitely. Is there any solution to check " if all packets have received successfully ", exit from while loop and do other statements .

import serial

```
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM28', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=0)

c=0
data=[]
msgparts=[]

while True:
  if ser.inWaiting():
     val = ser.readline(ser.inWaiting())
     print val
     print(val)
     fn1="image%s" %c
     c=c+1
     f = open(fn1, 'wb')
     f.write(val)
     print fn1
     f.close()
     msgparts.append(val) 

     #### Here I want to add new statements
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to check if all message parts are received, but you can use `break` to break out of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
while True:
```

at the top of the loop, you can start with:

```
message_complete = False
while not message_complete:
```

and in the loop have a line, such as:

```
if val[-1:] == '\n': 
    message_complete = True
```

(If the newline was the end of the message)

Of course, the break statement works here too.

How are you determining message complete?